# Need to create JMS Destination from within the EAR file in OC4J

Tags: jms, ejb-3.0

Need to create JMS Destination from within the EAR file in OC4J, (i.e.) Is there another way to create a JMS Destination rather than from the enterprise manager of OC4J.